# improve query below row_number() over (partition by

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Is there any way to improve query below, when I just check for one record it works faster(NAME='T  104') but when for all existing (113 records) records without NAME='T  104' it takes about 5 secs:

the one below takes 73 msec:

```
select 
    name, PRODUCTION_DAY, daytime 
from
    (select 
         name, PRODUCTION_DAY, daytime, 
         row_number() over (partition by name order by daytime desc) as seqnum
     from 
         RESULT_1 t 
     where 
         PRODUCTION_DAY < '15-May-2015'
    ) 
where 
    seqnum = 1 and NAME = 'T  104'
```

the one below takes 4 sec:

```
select 
    name, PRODUCTION_DAY, daytime 
from
    (select 
         name, PRODUCTION_DAY, daytime, 
         row_number() over (partition by name order by daytime desc) as seqnum
     from 
         RESULT_1 t 
     where 
         PRODUCTION_DAY < '15-May-2015'
    ) 
where 
    seqnum = 1
```

Thanks,
S

Comment: Can you please show _both_ queries, separately, and what their running times are?

Comment: see updated query

Comment: Can you run `EXPLAIN` on the two queries?  I'm not seeing an obvious answer for your observations.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the execution plan for both statements.  [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What is the data type of production_day? It looks like it would be date or timestamp but you filter on it using a string.

Comment: What so you expect? These queries will not return the same result because of different WHERE conditions.

Comment: (1) What is the number of rows for - (a) whole table (b) PRODUCTION_DAY < '15-May-2015'. (2) Do you have partition/index defined on PRODUCTION_DAY. (3) Please add the execution plans.

Answer (score -1):

Add an index on the column "name"

The difference between the 2 queries is an extra predicate in the where clause.

You could also try placing the filter by name inside the derived table

```
select 
    name, PRODUCTION_DAY, daytime 
from
    (select 
         name, PRODUCTION_DAY, daytime, 
         row_number() over (partition by name order by daytime desc) as seqnum
     from 
         RESULT_1 t 
     where 
         PRODUCTION_DAY < '15-May-2015'
      and NAME = 'T  104' 
    ) 
where 
    seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Mmm, i mis-read the question. Do you have an index on daytime?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should get the same result when you re-write the query like this:

```
SELECT NAME, 
    MAX(PRODUCTION_DAY) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY daytime) AS PRODUCTION_DAY, 
    MIN(daytime) AS daytime
FROM RESULT_1  
WHERE PRODUCTION_DAY < '15-May-2015'
    AND NAME = 'T  104'
GROUP BY NAME;
```

Depending on your indexes this might be the fastest way of doing it.